# Prediction of count data using XGB Poisson Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, xgboost, poisson

I'm working on predicting the n_clicks (which is always be an integer). i.e., my target variable will be an Integer and not a float type. For this, I've been trying **XGBOOST with parameter {objective = "count:poisson"}**. That's working fine. But I try **model.predict(x_test)** then it is always giving **"NAN"** values. (please see the screenshot). I couldn't find any example on Poisson Regression for predicting count data in python and most of the examples are in R language.

Can anyone have any suggestions!!

Thanks.
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you provide more code ? did you train your classifier?

Comment: @PV8, Added to question.

Comment: is your data a xgboost matrix? https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/xgboost-in-python

Comment: @PV8, I'm not providing the x, y variables in the form of DMatrix. Is it necessary to do that like  data_dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data=X,label=y)?

Comment: I am not working with xgb on regular base, but in most tutorials it is recommended to use the matrix, maybe this is the reason, why it is showing nan.

Comment: @PV8, in the https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/xgboost-in-python, it's saying to use the matrix but was used for cross validation. In my case problem is with prediction. Somebody has the similar problem that I'm facing i.e., getting NAN values. He raised this question on Official site [link] (https://discuss.xgboost.ai/t/prediction-are-all-nan-when-objective-is-count-poisson/703). But didn't get any solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199628/discussion-between-ravi-kumar-b-and-pv8).